# box-sizing: border-box reset font-family when using google fonts

Tags: css

I'm loading Google fonts but in addition I want to set all my html tags to be `border-box`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Heebo:400,700,900');
 body {
  font-family: 'Heebo';
}
```

Now for some reason **it's not working because of the `border-box`**, If I'll put it in this order it will work:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Heebo:400,700,900');
 * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Heebo';
}
```

Do you know why?

Comment: `@import` always has to be the first line in the stylesheet, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

Because [`@import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import) must be the 1st declaration in CSS (besides Charset rules)

> The `@import` CSS at-rule is used to import style rules from other style
>   sheets. These rules must precede all other types of rules, except
>   `@charset` rules; as it is not a nested statement, `@import` cannot be
>   used inside conditional group at-rules.

It would be better if you would use google fonts as a `link rel="stylesheet`

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Heebo';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Heebo" rel="stylesheet">
test
```